# grep float with percent sign in R

Tags: regex, r

I have long strings containing various text and numeric data like this

`a <- "$3,295,000; 8 Units; 4.08% Cap Rate; 9,360 SF Bldg;"`

and I would like to be able to extract the percentage, in this case `4.08%`.

How can I match this pattern with `grep()`?

Comment: Have some fun with it `scan(text=a, what="", sep=";", comment.char="C", strip.white=TRUE)[3]`, haha

Comment: Or `scan(text=a, what="", sep= " ")[4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a non-greedy match in `sub` for this:

```
sub('.*?([0-9.]+%).*', '\\1', a)
[1] "4.08%"
```

This will only match the first instance of the pattern in the string.

The `.*?` is non-greedy, so it won't "suck up" characters in the following pattern, which matches what you want.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(a, "[0-9.]+%")[[1]]
#[1] "4.08%"
```

If we only need to match the first instance, use `str_extract` instead of `str_extract_all`.  Though the other answer also does the same thing, it is better to use `str_extract_all` for multiple cases.

---

`grep` is used to return the index of a string whether it has a particular pattern or not.  Suppose if we use `grep`, it will return the index as 1 (as there is only one element in the `vector` and it matches the pattern)

```
grep("[0-9.]+$", a)
#[1] 1
```

For extracting substring either `str_extract` or `gsub` (from `base R` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you should be using is `(?:[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?%)`

It matches `Upto 2 digits` `.` `Upto 2 digits` `%`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW0nN8/2)**</kbd>